# CSS animation won't work unless using flexbox

Tags: css, animation, flexbox, css-animations

I can't figure out why, but my CSS animations stop working when I change the *display* property to anything else but *flex*. Here is the link to example in codepen:

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/piecdesmit/pen/OMYNZg?editors=1100)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  max-width: 560px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #222;
}

#button {
  background: #76B3FA;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 20px 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.45em;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

/* Hover state animation applied here */
#button:hover { 
  -webkit-animation: hover 1200ms linear 2 alternate;
  animation: hover 1200ms linear 2 alternate;
}

/* Active state animation applied here */
#button:active {
  -webkit-animation: active 1200ms ease 1 alternate;
  animation: active 1200ms ease 1 alternate; 
  background: #5F9BE0;
}
#button.gray { background: #D2D2D2; }
#button.gray:active { background: #b9b9b9; }

/* Active state animation keyframes below */

@-webkit-keyframes active { 
  0% {transform: scale(1,1);}
  90% {transform: scale(.9,.88);}
  100% {transform: scale(.92,.9);}
}

keyframes active { 
  0% {transform: scale(1,1);}
  90% {transform: scale(.9,.88);}
  100% {transform: scale(.92,.9);}
}

/* Hover state animation keyframes below */

@-webkit-keyframes hover { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  1.8% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.7% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  5.31% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  7.01% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  9.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  10.71% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.11% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.12% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.72% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  20.02% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  21.82% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  24.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  25.53% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.23% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.93% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  35.54% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  36.64% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  41.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  44.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  51.45% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  52.15% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  58.86% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  63.26% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  66.27% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  73.77% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  81.18% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  85.49% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  88.59% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}

@keyframes hover { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  1.8% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.7% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  5.31% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  7.01% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  9.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  10.71% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.11% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.12% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.72% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  20.02% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  21.82% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  24.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  25.53% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.23% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.93% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  35.54% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  36.64% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  41.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  44.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  51.45% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  52.15% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  58.86% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  63.26% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  66.27% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  73.77% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  81.18% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  85.49% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  88.59% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="button">Recommend</a>
<a href="#" id="button" class="gray">Another one</a>
```

Maybe someone can explain this?

Comment: `id` *should* be unique for each element, consider using `class="class-name"` for targetting multiple elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your links are `a` tags, which by default have a `display` value of `inline`. This means they are unaffected by sizing rules.

If you make them `#button {display:inline-block;}`, they will display in the same way but can be sized. You can then remove the flexbox.

This works with `display:flex` on the `body`, because flexbox overrides the `display:inline` and makes the links behave like they are `inline-block` elements.

P.S. do not give the buttons the same id (`#button`). This isn't really valid HTML and can cause strange behaviour. Better to give them a class instead (`.button`).

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  max-width: 560px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #222;
}

#button {
  display:inline-block;
  background: #76B3FA;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 20px 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.45em;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

/* Hover state animation applied here */
#button:hover { 
  -webkit-animation: hover 1200ms linear 2 alternate;
  animation: hover 1200ms linear 2 alternate;
}

/* Active state animation applied here */
#button:active {
  -webkit-animation: active 1200ms ease 1 alternate;
  animation: active 1200ms ease 1 alternate; 
  background: #5F9BE0;
}
#button.gray { background: #D2D2D2; }
#button.gray:active { background: #b9b9b9; }

/* Active state animation keyframes below */

@-webkit-keyframes active { 
  0% {transform: scale(1,1);}
  90% {transform: scale(.9,.88);}
  100% {transform: scale(.92,.9);}
}

keyframes active { 
  0% {transform: scale(1,1);}
  90% {transform: scale(.9,.88);}
  100% {transform: scale(.92,.9);}
}

/* Hover state animation keyframes below */

@-webkit-keyframes hover { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  1.8% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.7% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  5.31% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  7.01% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  9.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  10.71% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.11% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.12% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.72% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  20.02% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  21.82% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  24.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  25.53% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.23% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.93% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  35.54% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  36.64% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  41.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  44.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  51.45% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  52.15% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  58.86% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  63.26% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  66.27% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  73.77% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  81.18% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  85.49% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  88.59% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}

@keyframes hover { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  1.8% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.7% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  5.31% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  7.01% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  9.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  10.71% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.11% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.12% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.72% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  20.02% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  21.82% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  24.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  25.53% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.23% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.93% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  35.54% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  36.64% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  41.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  44.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  51.45% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  52.15% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  58.86% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  63.26% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  66.27% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  73.77% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  81.18% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  85.49% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  88.59% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="button">Recommend</a>
<a href="#" id="button" class="gray">Another one</a>
```